# What did Obama mean when he said this?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Donald Trump said that http://prntscr.com/duslay

Obama replied: At least I will go down as a president.

I know what he meant by that, but I don't get what's the context hidden between the lines, I don't get the roast, why did people find it so funny? Don't all presidents go down anyway? (be recorded or remembered in a particular way.)

Does he mean Donald Trump wont be remembered? or something?

Comment: "to go down in *history*" is the complete expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obama said this before Trump had been elected, under the assumption that he would lose the election. Obama means that even if he's remembered as a bad president, he'll still be remembered as a president. Under the assumption that Trump would lose, Obama means that Trump may be remembered, but not as a president.

Comment: In this situation we would say that Donald Trump ["has the last laugh"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+the+last+laugh), because he did get elected.

Comment: Yeah, he did. Haha, jokes on Obama.

Comment: Joke's on the entire country, but that's off-topic.  :)